# How to translate in Z WebGL?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, translate-animation, translate3d

My problem is that the function `translateZ` stops the code and doesn't work. Without this line: `particals.translateZ(50);` the code works but I want to translate the particals in the Z axis by 50 this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0070)http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_particles_random.html -->
<html lang="en"><meta style="visibility: hidden !important; display: block !important; width: 0px !important; height: 0px !important; border-style: none !important;"><embed id="__IDM__" type="application/x-idm-downloader" width="1" height="1" style="visibility: hidden !important; display: block !important; width: 1px !important; height: 1px !important; border-style: none !important; position: absolute !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important;"></meta><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>three.js webgl - particles</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #000000;
            margin: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-family:Monospace;
            font-size:13px;
            text-align:center;
            font-weight: bold;
            text-align:center;
        }

        a {
            color:#0078ff;
        }

        #info {
            color: #fff;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px; width: 100%;
            padding: 5px;
            z-index: 100;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org/" target="_blank">three.js</a> - webgl particles example
    </div>

    <script src="./three.js webgl - particles_files/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./three.js webgl - particles_files/three.js"></script>
    <script src="./three.js webgl - particles_files/Detector.js"></script>
    <script src="./three.js webgl - particles_files/stats.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

        var container, stats;
        var camera, scene, renderer, particles, geometry, materials = [], parameters, i, h, color;
        var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

        var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {

            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;

            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2( 0x000000, 0.0007 );

            geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            for ( i = 0; i < 50; i ++ ) {

                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
                vertex.x = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                vertex.y = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;
                vertex.z = Math.random() * 2000 - 1000;

                geometry.vertices.push( vertex );

            }

            parameters = [ [ [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 55 ], [ [0.95, 1, 1], 44 ], [ [0.90, 1, 1], 33 ], [ [0.85, 1, 1], 22 ], [ [0.80, 1, 1], 11 ] ];
            //parameters = [ [ 0xff0000, 5 ], [ 0xff3300, 4 ], [ 0xff6600, 3 ], [ 0xff9900, 2 ], [ 0xffaa00, 1 ] ];
            //parameters = [ [ 0xffffff, 5 ], [ 0xdddddd, 4 ], [ 0xaaaaaa, 3 ], [ 0x999999, 2 ], [ 0x777777, 1 ] ];

            for ( i = 0; i < parameters.length; i ++ ) {

                size  = parameters[i][1];
                color = parameters[i][0];

                //materials[i] = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { color: color, size: size } );

                materials[i] = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { size: size } );
                materials[i].color.setHSV( color[0], color[1], color[2] );

                particles = new THREE.ParticleSystem( geometry, materials[i] );

                //particles.rotation.x = Math.random() * 6;
                //particles.rotation.y = Math.random() * 6;
                particals.translateZ(50);
                particles.rotation.z = Math.random() * 30000;

                scene.add( particles );

            }

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            stats = new Stats();
            stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
            container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

            document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
            document.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false );

            //

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

        }

        function onWindowResize() {

            windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        }

        function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

        /*  mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
            mouseY = event.clientY - windowHalfY;*/

        }

        function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                /*mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;*/

            }

        }

        function onDocumentTouchMove( event ) {

            if ( event.touches.length === 1 ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                /*mouseX = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - windowHalfX;
                mouseY = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - windowHalfY;*/

            }

        }

        //

        function animate() {

            requestAnimationFrame( animate );

            render();
            stats.update();

        }

        function render() {

            var time = Date.now() * 0.00005;

            camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * 0.05;
            camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * 0.05;

            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            for ( i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {

                var object = scene.children[ i ];

                if ( object instanceof THREE.ParticleSystem ) {

                    object.rotation.y = time * ( i < 4 ? i + 1 : - ( i + 1 ) );

                }

            }

            for ( i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ ) {

                color = parameters[i][0];

                h = ( 360 * ( color[0] + time ) % 360 ) / 360;
                materials[i].color.setHSV( h, color[1], color[2] );

            }

            renderer.render( scene, camera );

        }


    </script><div><canvas width="1304" height="640" style="width: 1304px; height: 640px;"></canvas><div id="stats" style="width: 80px; opacity: 0.9; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px;"><div id="fps" style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 3px; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(0, 0, 34);"><div id="fpsText" style="color: rgb(0, 255, 255); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px;">49 FPS (0-54)</div><div id="fpsGraph" style="position: relative; width: 74px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);"><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 30px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 17.4px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 17.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.399999999999999px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 15px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.399999999999999px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 13.799999999999997px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.1px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.399999999999999px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 15px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 18.299999999999997px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 16.2px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 16.2px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.399999999999999px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.399999999999999px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.399999999999999px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 15px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 14.7px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 15.600000000000001px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 17.4px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 15.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 17, 51);"></span></div></div><div id="ms" style="padding: 0px 0px 3px 3px; text-align: left; background-color: rgb(0, 34, 0); display: none;"><div id="msText" style="color: rgb(0, 255, 0); font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 9px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 15px;">20 MS (3-13222)</div><div id="msGraph" style="position: relative; width: 74px; height: 30px; background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);"><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 24.9px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 16.5px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 28.5px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.15px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 28.05px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.75px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 24.9px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 24.9px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.15px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 28.05px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 24.9px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 25.2px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.75px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 24.75px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 25.2px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.75px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 24.75px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 25.05px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 25.05px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 25.05px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.15px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.9px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.45px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 25.05px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.3px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27.6px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span><span style="width: 1px; height: 27px; float: left; background-color: rgb(17, 51, 17);"></span></div></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misspelled "particles" on `particals.translateZ(50);` :)

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
particles.position.z += 50
```

?